# Using lambdas as Tornado callbacks

Tags: python, lambda, tornado

Is it possible? I am pretty new to Tornado (and Python itself) and I thought I could do something like that:

```
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_future(someFuture, lambda f: print f.result())
```

I simply get a syntax error. I thought function definitions and lambdas were more or less equivalent (both have type `function`). This just works fine:

```
def printFuture(f):
    print f.result()

tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_future(someFuture, printFuture)
```

I can also call printFuture method within a lambda:

```
def printFuture(f):
    print f.result()

tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_future(someFuture, lambda f: printFuture(f))
```

Could somebody explain me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python2 `print` is a statement. lambda can only be an expression

You can use

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

to get the function version of `print`

then just add a `(` and `)`

```
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_future(someFuture, lambda f: print(f.result()))
```